# Can't access subscribe method in unit-test

Tags: json, angular, unit-testing

I'm experiencing a very strange issue on a simple unit-test of a simple service get method. I'm using Angular 4 and cli so karma/jasmine for testing.

My service method:

```
getAccounts(): Observable<ApiData> {
    return this.authHttp.get('../../assets/mock_data/productsOverview.json')
      .map(
        data => {
          return JSON.parse(data['_body']);
        },
        err => {
          return err;
        }
      );
  }
```

And here is my test case:

```
import { TestBed, inject, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Http, BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, HttpModule, ConnectionBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { encodeTestToken } from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt-test-helpers';
import { AppModule } from '../app.module';
import { PersonalAccountsService, ApiData } from './personal-accounts.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    headerName: 'Authorization',
    headerPrefix: 'Bearer',
    tokenName: 'token',
    tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('token')),
    globalHeaders: [
      { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': localStorage.getItem('key') }],
  }), http, options);
}

const MyMockedService = {
  method: () => { }
}

describe('PersonalAccountsService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        PersonalAccountsService,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        MockBackend,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (mockBackend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
            return new Http(mockBackend, defaultOptions);
          },
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
        },
        {
          provide: AuthHttp,
          useFactory: (http) => {
            return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
              tokenName: 'token',
              tokenGetter: (() => encodeTestToken(this)),
              globalHeaders: [{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }]
            }), http);
          },
          deps: [Http],
        },
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpModule
      ],
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([PersonalAccountsService],
    (service: PersonalAccountsService) => {
      expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it('identification', async(
        inject(
            [PersonalAccountsService],
            (service: PersonalAccountsService) => {
              console.log('ENTERS HERE');
                service.getAccounts().subscribe(
                    data => {
                      console.log('NOT ENTERING HERE');
                    },
                    err => {
                      console.log('NOT ENTERING HERE');
                    },
                    () => {
                      console.log('NOT ENTERING HERE')
                    }
                );
            }
        )
    ));
});
```

Why this is happening? I'm trying to figure it our for a long time and I cannot even take an error to dive deeper.

Comment: What is authHttp? What is test setup? Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @estus authHttp is a helper for validating token. It doesn't alter the test reaction if I use it or not. I updated my question for you.

Comment: You're using MockBackend but aren't mocking the requests that should be done . The unit test involves too many moving parts. I would suggest to go keep it as isolated as possible. https://angular.io/guide/testing#isolated-unit-tests-vs-the-angular-testing-utilites . Consider replacing authHttp with some mock that returns a desired observable.

Comment: Can you provide an example for my case?

Answer (score 0):

The test likely performs requests but they weren't mocked with `MockBackend`.

The fact that code relies on third-party services (`AuthHttp`) makes it integration test rather than unit test.

To keep it as isolated as possible, every unit but tested unit should be mocked or stubbed. The service can be tested [in isolation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#isolated-unit-tests-vs-the-angular-testing-utilites) (in this case DI is not tested) or with `TestBed`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  const authHttpMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('authHttp', ['get']);
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      { provide: AuthHttp, useValue: authHttpMock }
      ...
});

it('...',  async(inject([PersonalAccountsService, AuthHttp], async (service, authHttpMock) => {
  const responseMock = Observable.of({ _body: ... });
  authHttpMock.get.and.returnValue(responseMock);

  const accounts$ = service.getAccounts();

  expect(authHttpMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);

  const accounts = await accounts$.toPromise();

  expect(accounts)...
  ...
```